# Torque on dipole in a non-uniform electric field

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, torque, dipole

What happens when an electric dipole is kept in a nonuniform electric field?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Torque on electric dipole placed in non uniform electric field](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/264655/)

Answer (score 0):

A dipole in a non-uniform electric field will experience a net torque that will eventually re-orient its poles until it find an equilibrium point (a minimum in potential energy) with respect to that uniform field.

For a dipole with electric dipole moment $p$ in an uniform electric field, the net torque it experiments is given by:

$$\vec{\tau}=\vec{p}\times \vec{E}$$

If the electric field is non-uniform and the dipole is sufficiently small, you could use this expression or expand it in Taylor series to include terms of higher order.

A more complete proof is given here: [Torque on electric dipole placed in non uniform electric field](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/264655/torque-on-electric-dipole-placed-in-non-uniform-electric-field)